# Git ignore everything in directories but one file type

Tags: git, vivado

I have this hierarchy, full of automatically generated folders:

```
| .gitignore
| ip
|   |ip1
|   |   |ip1.xci
|   |   |\other files\
|   |ip2
|   |   |ip2.xci
|   |   |\other files\
|   |ip3
|   |   |ip3.xci
|   |   |\other files\
|   |ip4
|   |   |ip4.xci
|   |   |\other files\
...
```

I want to write a rule to ignore everything but the .xci files (necessary to regenerate everything else), how do I write such a rule?

I have tried writing rules like:

```
ip/**/*
!ip/**/*.xci
```

but it doesn't work.

As I have understood it, git won't look for files in directories it has ignored even if the patter would match. Is there a way not to write a line for every file I want to keep? As other folders will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unignore directories to make `git` look into them:

```
ip/**/*
!ip/**/*/
!ip/**/*.xci
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `.gitignore` file associated with every git repository if not just create one.

You can Ignore directories by entering the directory name into the file (with a slash appended):

```
dir_to_ignore/
```

More information is [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

You can mention all what you want to ignore there as extension as well for files

Comment: Op is asking for a way to ignore some folders BUT some file types within these folders. Not just ignore something